# How can I create a bash install script for my Wordpress sites setup (WP+plugins+theme)?

Tags: plugins, themes, installation, scripts

I build a lot of websites with Wordpress, and my initial setup is basically always the same :

- Latest version of WP
- Latest versions of about 5 plugins
- My naked development theme

Instead of downloading/uploading these things separately and do that by hand each time I start a new project, I'd like to create a bash script that would do this :

- Download the latest version of Wordpress
- Unzip
- Download the latest version of plugin X
- Unzip to WP plugins folder
- Download my naked theme
- Unzip to themes folder

Now downloading the latest WP is easy (http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz), downloading my naked theme too, but I'm having trouble getting the latest version of a plugin, as they are not called `latest.tar.gz` but specifict names with the version (ex: wptouch.1.9.26.zip)

EDIT : So I'm wonderning now if it's possible to use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) in my bash script to find the exact URL of the Current version of a plugin. The idea would be to fetch the page, and then find the value of the `href` that is in the paragraph just after the `<h3>Current Version</h3>`.

Here's an example, all plugin download pages on WP are like this :

```
<h3>Current Version</h3>
<p class="unmarked-list">
    <a href="http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.1.1.2.zip">1.1.2</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Retrieving and installing files (WordPress core, plugins, themes) is easy, but the trickier part is getting the database settled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062513/install-wordpress-using-bash-shell-without-visiting-wp-admin-install-php

Answer (score 4):

To always get latest plugin take for example my plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-file-monitor-plus/

the download link for the latest is:

http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-file-monitor-plus.1.1.zip

but if you remove the version from the download link you always get the latest version:

http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-file-monitor-plus.zip

EDIT: Have you considered keeping a folder of the latest wordpress and plugins unpacked? Then as soon as a new plugin or wordpress comes out you simply unpack that over what you have. Then your bash script just packages the whole lot to be used on an install.

Comment: Dammit, that was easy, thanks. Now I'm off bash scripting, I hope I can put something together. I'll post the result here.

Comment: One question though, in your example wordpress-file-monitor-plus.zip is listed under "Development Version", that's not the same as the latest stable version, is it ?

Comment: Oh I see. This maybe not the latest version... It might be what's currently latest in the trunk. Sorry I might have miss informed you.

Comment: @Brady's edit : Yes right now I have a "starter" WP install, with all my most used plugins installed + a blank theme. That works, but as plugins (and WP) get updates rather often, I was looking for something completely automated.

Comment: @mike23 I'm out of ideas on how to get latest version. I've tried scouring the web but with no luck. You could use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/update-notifier/ to be notified when your handful of plugins are updated so you can keep on top of updating your plugin repository

Comment: I would go with SVN here. [There](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/) you can checkout/export the tag with the highest number or just the trunk from every plugin. Same goes for the [WordPress Core](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/).

Comment: Couldn't you just open `http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/plugin-name/trunk/readme.txt`, parse out the `Stable Tag: X` line, then download `http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/plugin-name.X.zip` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create the bash script:

```
touch wp_plugins_theme.sh
```

Make Executable:

```
chmod +x ./wp_plugins_theme.sh
```

Copy this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  This script is to automate a common WP setup.
#
#   - Download the latest version of Wordpress
#   - Unzip
#   - Download the latest version of plugin X
#   - Unzip to WP plugins folder
#   - Download theme
#   - Unzip to themes folder

: ' Define Directory
'

# Change to your directory name
# Final site will be $PWD/$dirname/www/

dirname=ExampleWPPluginsTheme

# WordPress Directories used later

plugins=$PWD/$dirname/www/wp-content/plugins
themes=$PWD/$dirname/www/wp-content/themes

: ' Clear Example Dir
'

rm -rf $PWD/$dirname
mkdir -p $PWD/$dirname/www
cd $PWD/$dirname;

: ' Download the latest version of Wordpress
'

curl -OL "https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz"

: ' Unzip
'

tar -zxvf "./latest.tar.gz" -C 'www' --strip-components=1

: ' Download the latest version of plugin X
'

curl -OL "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/query-monitor.latest-stable.zip"
curl -OL "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-optimize.latest-stable.zip"

: ' Unzip to WP plugins folder
'

tar -zxvf "./query-monitor.latest-stable.zip" -C $plugins
tar -zxvf "./wp-optimize.latest-stable.zip" -C $plugins

: ' Download theme
'

curl -OL "https://github.com/Automattic/_s/archive/master.zip"

: ' Unzip to themes folder
'

tar -zxvf "./master.zip" -C $themes

: ' Done
'

# List the folder contents

ls -la $PWD
```

Run the command

```
./wp_plugins_theme.sh
```

Comment: I know that this is old now but it's the closest one to the right answer which should simply be `https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/plugin-name.latest-stable.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I created a bash script to update Wordpress using subversion as they [recommend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion).

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: upgrade_wordpress.sh X.X.X
# http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/699613/327074
die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

# check that there is one argument
[ "$#" -eq 1 ] || die "usage: upgrade_wordpress.sh X.X.X"
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/2220646/327074
response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$1/)
# check that the tag repository exists, i.e. returns a HTTP 200 status code
[ "$response" -eq 200 ] || die "Couldn't find Wordpress version, http error: $response"
# Take a backup
mysqldump -u root -p wordpress > wordpress_upgrade_to_$1_bak.sql
# Updating to a New Stable Version
cd /path/to/wordpress/dir/
svn sw http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$1/ .
```

I've modified this to do the installation. This second script is untested but it should get you started. You will need to write your own create_wordpress_database_and_user.sql - but you didn't ask for that in the question anyway, so maybe you can ignore it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: install_wordpress.sh X.X.X /path/to/wordpress/dir
# http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/699613/327074
die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}
# check that there are two arguments
[ "$#" -eq 2 ] || die "usage: install_wordpress.sh X.X.X /path/to/wordpress/dir"
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/2220646/327074
response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$1/)
# check that the tag repository exists, i.e. returns a HTTP 200 status code
[ "$response" -eq 200 ] || die "Could not find Wordpress version, http error: $response"
# create directory if needed
if [ ! -d $2 ]; then
    mkdir $2
fi
# Install the database
mysql -u root -p < create_wordpress_database_and_user.sql
# Checking out stable version
cd $2
svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/$1/ .
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `git clone` as a sort of poor mans bash.

The WordPress git is updated every 30 minutes so I clone it into my own repo with my own plugins/themes or just pull directly from it.

The whole thing is pretty fast, in fact it is only about 2 lines,  and the only thing I have to do manually is create the local DB and edit the config.php. It can be a bit tricky making sure you update WordPress to the latest version if you want to do it every 30minutes, but I typically only use the stable version, and keep the dev version in another environment.

It looks like this:

```
mkdir wordpress-project
git clone ..url-to-my-wordpress-base
```

The other downside is that it is a bit hard to get plugins from the actual WordPress repo through git, it is possible to do it, using the `git svn` command but I find it's not easy to work with, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bash script to install wordpress.

This script will automate the following:

- Downlaod and install Wordpress automatically
- Create Default Users with passwords
- Install all default plugins
- Install the default or custom theme by zip url you mostly used.

You can find script on github.com

https://github.com/jeoga/wordpress_install_bash_script